# Destroying Spark UDFs explicitly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

I have a long-running SparkContext in which I define a UDF which takes in a large amount of data as its input. I noticed that the memory this UDF uses is not released back up until the SparkContext is terminated. I would like to find a way of claiming this memory back before the application terminates. I have tried the following with no luck:

1. Registering another UDF with the same name to trick Spark into releasing the memory used in the first one.
2. I checked ContextCleaner in Spark but it seems all the functions therein are private and not available to the users.
3. I checked the UDFRegistration class which has methods for registering UDFs but not there is nothing to register them.

Is there a way to delete/destroy a UDF in Spark while SparkContext is still alive?